# On the sides of the application, is it possible to change the gray frames to black?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

On the sides of the application, is it possible to change the gray frames to black?

[gray frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtbxU.jpg)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO4x6.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb SO's [recommendations addressed to new users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour); then do read what's [on-topic here] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please, provide your code as text (no images) and a minimal reproducible sample (and your tries). Take also a look to https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Answer (score 0):

Script

window.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";